# Dockerfile can't find output on linux

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile

```
ARG JEKYLL_VERSION=4
FROM jekyll/jekyll:$JEKYLL_VERSION as BUILD

COPY --chown=jekyll:jekyll . /srv/jekyll
RUN ls -lah /srv/jekyll

RUN jekyll build
RUN ls /srv/jekyll/_site/

FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:alpine
ADD build/nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY --chown=101:101 --from=BUILD /srv/jekyll/_site/ /var/www
```

Which does build perfectly locally, but not on the Linux Jenkins Buildslave:

```
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 28 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux-musl]
Configuration file: /srv/jekyll/_config.yml
            Source: /srv/jekyll
       Destination: /srv/jekyll/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.186 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
Removing intermediate container 2b064db0ccaa
 ---> 1e19e78f593a
Step 6/9 : RUN ls /srv/jekyll/_site/
 ---> Running in 194d35c3f691
[91mls: /srv/jekyll/_site/: No such file or directory
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c ls /srv/jekyll/_site/' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Changing `RUN jekyll build` to `RUN jekyll build && ls /srv/jekyll/_site/` lists the jekyll output as expected.
Why is the output of the `jekyll build` not stored? If I remove the `ls` command, the output can't be found in the later stage.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because [the image declares that directory as a `VOLUME`](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/blob/master/repos/jekyll/Dockerfile#L192).  This is probably a bug and I'd suggest reporting it as a GitHub issue; it won't affect any of the documented uses of the image to remove that line.

At the end of the day Jekyll is just a [Ruby gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll) (library).  So while that image installs a lot of things, for your use it might be enough to start from a [`ruby`](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby) image, install the gem, and use it:

```sh
FROM ruby:3.1
RUN gem install jekyll
WORKDIR /site
COPY . .
RUN jekyll build
```

If your directory tree contains a Ruby `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, you could also `COPY` those into the image and `RUN bundle install` instead.

Alternatively, since Jekyll is a static site generator, you should get the same results if you build the site on the host or in a container, and another good path could be to install Ruby and Jekyll on your host (maybe in an `rbenv` gemset) and then `COPY` the site from the host into the Nginx image; skip the first stage entirely.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, I guess I would have never found that this is a volume, I agree that's more in BUG regions.
What baffled me was, that this builds fine on Mac / Windows but not on Linux. Maybe some edge case?

Comment: That's surprising; especially on MacOS, there's a hidden Linux VM so the mechanics of building an image should be literally identical.